# File length and Byte[] size doesn't match in JAVA

Tags: java, file

I am trying to convert a image to byte[] which will be sent to a service, will determine the file size if it is allowable or not. But I am getting different size in of actual image file and byte[].
My test code:

```
File file=new File("path/photo.jpg"); //around 4.5 MB
img = ImageIO.read(file);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", bos );
byte [] data = bos.toByteArray();
System.out.println("fileSize:"+file.length());
System.out.println("byteSize:"+ data.length);
```

***output***

```
 fileSize:4544732 //equals to actual image size
 byteSize:1468863
```

My target is: I need to measure the actual filesize from the byte[] of that image.

Comment: You are re-encoding the image, obviously with different parameters (as you don’t know which parameters were originally used). But where’s the problem? You have to decide what you are going to send, A) the file you already have: then, don’t load it into an image nor re-encode. Just read the file into a byte array and transfer or B) the image you have in memory, freshly encoded. Then, the file size is irrelevant. You’ll send the byte array resulting from your encoding operation and only the size of the byte array matters.

Comment: Purely from your description it sounds like you want option A from what Holger suggested. In that case, any mention of ImageIO is unnecessary and wrong in your code.

Comment: Why do you think that the size of the file must be the same as the number of bytes in the [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) that is created by reading that file?

Comment: I had misconception about image. Now I understand it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageIO is not needed for your use-case.

Try this instead.

```java
final byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
```

Comment: And if they first want to check the file size before reading the whole thing simply `file.length()`.